# Can I hardcode user credentials for TwitterAPI oauth?

Tags: android, api, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

Very new mobile developer here...

I am trying to retrieve a list of tweets from a specific user or in a spefic hashtag. The catch is, customer wants that user should not enter any credentials or need to have a twitter account at all.

I think that I need to be able to hardcode a username and password to be able use twitter api calls with them to show results of mentioned tweet queries.

Is this really possible to achieve without twitter api ever asking user for credentials?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Two-legged Oauth is what you are looking for. Twitter generates tokens for each user for each app, thus eliminating passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to login to do these searches. To search for a hashtag you do like this:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23html5  //searches for the hashtag #html5

To search for tweets by a spesific user you do like this:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:rgullhaug  //searches for tweets written by me (@rgullhaug)

Comment: This is the trick I was looking for, though there is one caveat, that is search API will only return tweets from at most 6-9 days ago. If queried target has not tweeted for say, 10 days, nothing will be returned. In case anyone needs to know in future.